# Executar ação depois de 2 minutos sem mexer o mouse

Tags: php, jquery

Como criar uma função em `jQuery` que redirecione o visitante para uma página após o ele não mexer o mouse por 2 minutos ou mais?

Exemplo: O usuário está na pagina **produtos.php** e caso o usuário fique parado com o mouse ou ele esteja em outra aba/guia *(Facebook por exemplo)*, depois de **2** minutos ele **redirecione** pra `aguarde.php`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Código adaptado do @Rod

```
$(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
    }, 120000);
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) { 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
    }, 120000);
});
```

No meu exemplo foi adicionado a função `window.location.href` que cria o **redirecionamento** e **foi removido** a função que fazia com que ao passar o mouse sobre a página *exclui-se* o conteúdo da página.

Foi adicionada uma uma contagem em **milisegundos** equivalente a 2 minutos (**120.000** milisegundos é igual à **120 segundos**, que é igual a **2 minutos**, pois **1 minuto** tem **60 segundos**).

Após 2 minutos é redirecionado para http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Agora basta que você edite-o com a `URL` para qual você deseja que ocorra o redirecionamento. No caso:

```
window.location.href = "aguarde.php";
```

Agora está *100% funcional*, do jeito que você queria.

### [Demontração](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DY3LV/1/show/)

**[Link do Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DY3LV/1/)**

**Obs:** Nos exemplos criados no *jsFiddle* foi dado apenas 3.000 milisegundos = 3 segundos, para não ter que esperar 2 minutos para ver o funcionamento.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar um timer em um evento `mousemove`

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
 $(function() { //onload
   setEvent();

});

$(document).on('mousemove', function() { //mouse move 
    if (timeout !== null) {
        $(document.body).text('');
        clearTimeout(timeout); //clear no timer
    }
    setEvent(); //seta ele novamente para caso aja inatividade faça o evento
});

function setEvent(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $(document.body).text('Mouse idle for 3 sec'); //Teu evento após terminar o timer
    }, 3000); //tempo do timer
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mw2gD/72/)

Referencia:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094272/jquery-detect-if-the-mouse-is-still)

Comment: Se eu executo esse código e fico mexendo o mouse logo de inicio por mais de 3 segundos e depois paro e deixo o mouse parado ele não executa. Ele só executa se quando eu iniciar o script, ficar com o mouse parado

Comment: E também se fico com o mouse encima do documento ele não redireciona, só se fica fora do documento

Comment: Mostre seu código, você pode iniciar o timeout e apenas no mousemove dar um clear nele

Comment: Editei, teste-o

Comment: Desculpe por estar ressuscitando o tópico, porém estou precisando exatamente disso em meu sistema. Esse código só funciona no caso do mouse? e no caso do teclado? pois muitas pessoas podem estar no chat por exemplo.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos sim, veja que o evento é no "mousemove", se for por teclado, mude-o para keyup

Comment: Certo Rod, na verdade gostaria para os dois. Como eu faria nesse caso?

Answer (score 1):

Sem uso de *add-ons*, você pode fazer um bloco de comandos assim:

```
(function()
{
    var mouse = {};
    // mouse.timer --> tempo para ação
    // mouse.moved --> callback quando o mouse é movido
    // mouse.action --> sua ação de 2 minutos
    mouse.action = function ()
    {
        // 2 minutos. Bye!
    };
    mouse.moved = function ()
    {
        if(mouse.timer)
            // O tempo já estava definido.
            clearTimeout(mouse.timer); // Então para.
        mouse.timer = setTimeout(mouse.action, 120000)
    };
    addEventListener("mousedown", mouse.moved); // ao segurar ou clicar
    addEventListener("mousemove", mouse.moved); // ao mover
    addEventListener("touchstart", mouse.moved); // ao tocar
    addEventListener("load", function ()
    {
        mouse.timer = setTimeout(mouse.action, 120000)
        // Já execute o tempo para ação quando a página carregar.
    });
    // Você pode acrescentar:
    // addEventListener("keydown", mouse.moved)
    // se quiser que o mesmo aconteça ao pressionar uma tecla.
})()
```