# Como fazer setTimeout rodar "infinitamente"

Tags: javascript, loop, timeout

Preciso que uma função seja executada a cada 2 minutos.
Encontrei neste link uma solução para a minha necessidade:

[Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26088/executar-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-depois-de-2-minutos-sem-mexer-o-mouse)

O Código abaixo, chama um alert após 5 segundos ao deixar o mouse parado.

**Observação**
Coloquei 5 segundos para poupar tempo no teste.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       alert('executa função');
    }, 5000);
});

$(document).on('mouseover', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) { 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('executa função');
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

**O que eu preciso:**
Eu preciso que este script funcione da mesma forma só que em um loop infinito, onde a cada 5 segundos será chamado o alert.

Eu tentei abraçar o código com:

```
while(0 = 0){

}
```

Mas não funcionou...

Como faço então para que minha função seja executada infinitamente a cada 5 segundos automaticamente?

Comment: isto mesmo...deixar ele tipo: contou 5s ->chama function, contou +5s -> chama function...forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o evento ocorra infinitamente sem o mouseover, basta remove-lo. Veja:

```
function Temporizador(initiate) {
    if (initiate !== true) {
        alert("Olá mundo");
    }
    setTimeout(Temporizador, 5000);
}

$(function() {
    Temporizador(true);
});
```

Se chamar o `Temporizador(true);` com true, ele não executa o primeiro `alert`, mas somente a cada 5 segundos.

Comment: Bingo! funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), que faz basicamente mas mesma coisa, mas repetindo a cada período

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeInterval = null;
$(document).on('mouseover', function() {
    if (timeInterval !== null) { 
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
    }

    timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
        alert('executa função');
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas e como faço para isso acontecer automaticamente, independente de o mouse estar parado ou não...

Comment: deixe o setInterval fora do evento. Por exemplo, onde eu atribuo 
var timeInterval = null;
faça 
var timaInterval = setInterval(function() {
        alert('executa função');
    }, 5000);

Comment: Perfeito, desse jeito funciona conforme eu precisava. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Podias também usar `$(document).one(` para executar só uma vez e assim poupar uma variável global.