# Como exibir elemento por inatividade do mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por exemplo, o usuário entra na página e, enquanto não mover o mouse depois de certo tempo, aparece um elemento.

Comment: eu tentei isso $('.teste').hide().delay(1000).fadeIn 9000 no caso ele fica aprecendo automaticamente

Comment: Eu tenho a tela inicial ...se não mexer o mouse aparecer uma div por cima da telainicial ...mas essa div só pode aparecer se a pessoa ficar um tempo sem mexer o mouse...

Answer (score 2):

Olha esse exemplo:

```
    $(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
    }, 120000);
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) { 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
    }, 120000);
    });
```

Nesse código, verifica o movimento do mouse, se em dois minutos o mouse não for movimentado ele direciona para outra página usando `window.location.href`.

Sendo assim, apenas terá que alterar o código removendo o `window.location.href` e adcionando a ação que mostra a sua DIV.

Fonte: [Executar ação depois de 2 minutos sem mexer o mouse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26088/executar-a%c3%a7%c3%a3o-depois-de-2-minutos-sem-mexer-o-mouse/26107#26107)

Answer (score -1):

Sobre ficar o mouse parado não conheço nada específico porém você pode fazer um javascript para exibir a div após algum tempo... segue exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function carregar_tempo() {
document.getElementById('box').style.display='block';
}

</script>

<body onload="setTimeout('carregar_tempo()', 1000)">

<div id="box" style="display:none;">conteúdo</div>
```

1000 equivale a 1 segundo, só alterar.