# Redireccionar para a próxima página depois de tempo de inatividade

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia! 
Eu estou a criar um sistema de classificações, consiste em **escolher a opção**, o utilizador é redireccionando para **outra página para deixar um comentário**, e de **seguida** mostra **outra página a agradecer**, e volta tudo ao princípio.

Porém há utilizadores que só escolhem a opção e vão embora e permanece a página do comentário... 
O que eu queria fazer é por exemplo, **depois de 15 segundos** (por exemplo) caso não haja movimento, a página automaticamente reconhecesse o comentário, validar apenas como um comentário vazio, e passasse para a página do "agradecimento", caso contrário desde o ínicio se o utilizador estiver a escrever ele poderá demorar o tempo que quiser.

Eu já vi várias tópicos parecidos mas era com `sessions`, para deslogar o usuário, e eu não estou a utilizar nenhuma `session`! Obrigada!

Comment: isto seria possível com javascript usando um `setTimeout` e verificar se ouve algum comentario

Comment: Pode me mostrar um exemplo por favor?

Comment: irei fazer um pequeno exemplo aguarde.

Answer (score -1):

Tente colocar o seguinte trecho na página em que você necessita este redirecionamento:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="15 ; URL= pagina.html">
```

Comment: Mas assim ele vai sempre fazer isso mesmo que o utilizador esteja a inserir o comentário

Comment: Neste caso, verifique o [link] (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26088/executar-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-depois-de-2-minutos-sem-mexer-o-mouse)